# Build Screen lock widget for android less than 4.2

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen, android-music-player

I read a lot of threads about lock screen widget and I can't understand whether its possible to build lock screen widget for Android version less than 4.2?

I have a music app and I want a widget in lock screen that can play, pause, play next and last song, similar to iPhone lock screen when iPod playing and same as music player for Android.

If it's not possible for Android 2.1 - 4.1 then why can the native music player in android 2.3.3 on Samsung Galaxy S2 do it?

Comment: i am also searching for same question. Have you got any solution?

Comment: hello, I am also searching for the same. Did you got any way to add widget to lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like duplicate question. Please check my answer here for the lockScreen control you required.

Answer: **[Media Control on Lock Screen like Google Play Music in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652078/media-control-on-lock-screen-like-google-play-music-in-android/25617234#25617234)**