# Crashlytics WebHook for Slack is not working

Tags: webhooks, crashlytics, slack, google-fabric

I have successfully configured Crashlytics Webhook with Slack. I have also tested it with the Test Message given in Crashlytics console. Test message working fine.

But, when I have an actual crash in Crashlytics, it is not getting triggered into the Slack. I don't know where is the issue. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mike from Fabric here. I responded over email, but will make the answer public as well.

For this integration, you've set the impact level to 5 which means that only issues that are the most impactful will be mentioned in Slack. If you want to be notified of every new issue, set the impact level to 1.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I will update you over here or on email for same.

Comment: Hi Mike, is there a way to integrate Crashlytics to skype?

Comment: None that I'm aware of unless it can take a webhook - https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/custom-web-hooks.html?web%20hooks#custom-web-hooks

Comment: Same problem here.

All the configuration is ok. Send test is ok. Level 1 is set and I also received mails about crashes. But the slack integration don't receive it. 

I think maybe it doesn't work since I linked my fabric app with the firebase app ? :/

Comment: I've got the same problem as @Grifas

Comment: If you're hitting this issue with my answer not helping, contact the Fabric support team. Another possibility is that a new issue hasn't been triggered. If the impact level is 1, a brand new issue needs to happen. If you've caused a second crash on an issue that's been around before, the notification won't be triggered.

Comment: Its now working with Firebase crashlytics. I recently configured it and now i am getting alerts on my slack channel.

Comment: How do you change the level of impact to 5 ?

Comment: I no longer work on the product, but to my knowledge, you can't change the impact level on your own. It required more of the same crash and/or users hitting the crash to increase the impact level.

Answer (score 1):

I configured the firebase crashlytics as it is noted using the webhooks from slack ,
Result is i have a successful testing message sent to the slack channel but not the actual errors even though i have checked all type of crashes, new and recurring, some said a thing about impact level need to be changed to 1 but i can't find how .