# Any Titanium solutions for controlling Android audio from lock screen / home screen?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop

I am currently using `Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer` to play audio in my app. I am using the following module to allow control of said audio from the lock screen / homescreen in iOS:

https://github.com/hoyo/TiRemoteControl

Is there an Android equivalent of this solution for Titanium? A module perhaps? Or has anyone managed to get this to work using Hyperloop?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it is not possible with the native SDK and there is no (opensource) module. You can try it with Hyperloop (might work) or create a custom Android module yourself (better solution). Have a look at the RemoteControlClient (deprecated in 21) / MediaSession  API and this thread: [Media Control on Lock Screen like Google Play Music in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652078/media-control-on-lock-screen-like-google-play-music-in-android)

Another solution would be to ask in the tislack.org/ #job section to find a dev who can create the module for you